# ошибка на python библиотека aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

[image]

пишет в терминале: Unrecognised argument(s): LaveL

Comment: Потому что не `Lavel` а `level`

Answer (score 0):

Это должно решить проблему:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

logging.INFO выводит всю информацию (зачастую, лишнюю), на вашем месте я бы задал logging.ERROR, этот уровень логирования будет выводить только ошибки (что, на мой взгляд, более удобно)

Сделать это можно так:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
```